# Is it Possible to Set the Column to be Updated via a Prepared Statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a function that can alter the value of a column in a table, where the table, column, and values are not predetermined. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
UPDATE :tbl SET :column = :value;
```

to accomplish this, or can parameters only be bound for values?

**EDIT**:

Or is this the only way to accomplish this:

```
$query = "UPDATE".$tbl." SET ".$column." = ".$value.";";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do that. Prepared statements allow the database to optimize a query plan for the particular query. If it doesn't know what table or column, it cannot create the query plan.

Comment: Thats what i figured is there any other option besides what i edited in?

Comment: You can create a prepared statement as you have above, and then still use the :value part in place of $value in a prepared statement. If you do this though and the $tbl or $column values are coming from user input, you would have to make sure they are valid and properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters can only be bound to values and not tables/columns.

Comment: Thats what i figured is there any other option besides what i edited in?